# How do you deserialize JSON to a map/dictionary of records in F#?

Tags: json, parsing, f#

Here's the shape of the JSON:

```
{
  "Alice": {
    "Age": 30,
    "Address": {
      "City": "New York",
      "State": "NY"
    }
  },
  "Bob": {
    "Age": 6,
    "Address": {
      "City": "Chicago",
      "State": "IL"
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to deserialize it to something like the type `Map<String, Person>` where `Person` and `Address` are is a records. The name of the person should be the key in the `Map`.

I've tried `FSharp.Data`'s `JsonProvider`, but it gives each person their own type like so:

[image]

Is there a library that better handles this situation?

Comment: If you have the JSON under your control, I'd change it to a list of person objects. The current version is not very suitable to map it to what you want. `[ {"name": "Alice", "Age": 30 }, {"name": "Bob", "Age": 6 }]` would be easily deserializeable by Fsharp.Data.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm consuming an external API, so I can't control its structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to (or cannot) use FSharp.Data for any reason you could also try [Thoth.Json](https://mangelmaxime.github.io/Thoth/index.html) which is available for both Fable as well as normal .NET. In Thoth you can either use Autoencoders/Autodecoder which will try to handle the conversion for you if your F# types closely resemble the used JSON or you write your own encoding/decoding functions.

A typed example (as a console app) that should fit your usecase (if I understood it correctly) could look like this.

```
let testString = """
{
  "Alice": {
    "Age": 30,
    "Address": {
      "City": "New York",
      "State": "NY"
    }
  },
  "Bob": {
    "Age": 6,
    "Address": {
      "City": "Chicago",
      "State": "IL"
    }
  }
}
"""

open Thoth.Json.Net

type Address =
    { City : string
      State : string }

type Person =
    { Age : int
      Address: Address}

let decodeAddress : Decoder<Address> =
    Decode.object
        (fun get ->
            { City = get.Required.Field "City" Decode.string
              State = get.Required.Field "State" Decode.string })

let decodePerson : Decoder<Person> =
    Decode.object
        (fun get ->
            { Age = get.Required.Field "Age" Decode.int
              Address = get.Required.Field "Address" decodeAddress})

let decodeMap jsonString =
    Decode.fromString (Decode.keyValuePairs decodePerson) jsonString
    |> Result.map (fun namePersonList ->
        namePersonList
        |> Map.ofList)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    match decodeMap testString with
    | Ok res -> printfn "%A" res
    | Error e -> printfn "%s" e
    0
```

Answer (score 2):

You still can use FSharp.Data's `JsonValue` instead of the provider:

```
JsonValue.Parse(json).Properties()
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

output:

```
("Alice",
 {
  "Age": 30,
  "Address": {
    "City": "New York",
    "State": "NY"
  }
})
("Bob",
 {
  "Age": 6,
  "Address": {
    "City": "Chicago",
    "State": "IL"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem is that your JSON structure is using a record to represent a list of people (with names as the key). If you can change it as suggested in the comment, then that's probably the best approach.

Alternatively, you can still read this with F# Data by using the type provider to define a type for the person:

```
type Person = JsonProvider<"""{
    "Age": 30,
    "Address": { "City": "New York", "State": "NY" }
  }""">
```

Now, assuming `input` is your input string with multiple people, you can read it using the `JsonValue` parser, iterate over all the top-level record fields manually, but then parse individual people in your JSON using your new `Person` type:

```
[ for name, person in JsonValue.Parse(input).Properties() ->
    name, Person.Root(person) ]
```

This gives you a list of tuples containing a name and a typed object for each person (and you get the usual benefits of type providers, i.e. you can access address and age using `.`)

Comment: @DharmaTurtle if you want to keep on using the type provider for data exploration this answer is the most fitting for your use case. Thanks Tomas for pointing out this solution!